Parse HCL block into Golang map
I am implementing acceptance tests for a terraform provider, and I would like to use the same input variable to write my test plan and to assert that my resource is properly setup.
For my usecase I need to use TestCheckTypeSetElemNestedAttrs from Terraform Plugin SDK that expects a map[string]string.
How can I use the same variable to generate a Terraform block and a map[string]string easily (preferably without having to define structs).
I am looking for something like that :
func TestAccResource(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    pr := TestAccProtoV6ProviderFactories

    name := "the name"

    innerBlock := `{
        field1 = 0
        field2 = false
        field4 = "value"
    }`

    innerBlockMap map[string]string := <------------ How to parse innerBlock to a map[string]string here ? 

    resource.Test(t, resource.TestCase{
        ProtoV6ProviderFactories: pr,
        Steps: []resource.TestStep{
            {
                Config: fmt.Sprintf(`
                resource "myprovider_myresource" "test" {
                    name = %[1]q
                    innerField = %[1]s
                }`, innerBlock, name),
                Check: resource.ComposeAggregateTestCheckFunc(
                    resource.TestCheckResourceAttr("myprovider_myresource.test", "name", name),
                    resource.TestCheckTypeSetElemNestedAttrs("myprovider_myresource.test", "name", innerBlockMap),
                ),
            },
        },
    })
}


FWIW what you have in innerBlock is not actually a "block" as HCL thinks of it. That's an object constructor expression, for constructing a value of an object type. Therefore you'd need to parse it as a naked HCL expression (hclsyntax.ParseExpression) and then evaluate it, rather than parsing it as an HCL configuration file (hcl.ParseConfig).

Try hclsyntax.ParseExpression and gohcl.DecodeExpression:
package ...

import (
    ...
    "testing"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/gohcl"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclsyntax"
)

func TestAccResource(t *testing.T) {
    ...

    innerBlock := `{
        field1 = 0
        field2 = false
        field4 = "value"
    }`

    expr, diag := hclsyntax.ParseExpression([]byte(innerBlock), "example.hcl", hcl.InitialPos)
    if diag.HasErrors() {
        t.Error(diag.Error())
    }

    var innerBlockMap map[string]string
    diag = gohcl.DecodeExpression(expr, nil, &innerBlockMap)
    if diag.HasErrors() {
        t.Error(diag.Error())
    }

    ...
}

